# compute and plot monthly mean SST anomalies and plot with xarray multindex (pangeo tutorial gallery)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm working through the pangeo tutorial gallery and am stuck on the [ENSO exercise at the end of xarray](http://gallery.pangeo.io/repos/pangeo-data/pangeo-tutorial-gallery/xarray.html#ENSO-exercise)

you'll need to download some files:

```
%%bash
git clone https://github.com/pangeo-data/tutorial-data.git
```

Then:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

# load all files
ds_all = xr.open_mfdataset('./tutorial-data/sst/*nc', combine='by_coords')
# slice for enso3.4 region
sst_enso = ds_all.sel(lat=slice(-5,5), lon=slice(-170+360,-120+360))
# subset years to match hint at the bottom
sst_enso = sst_enso.sel(time=sst_enso.time.dt.year>=1982)
# groupby each timepoint and find mean for entire spatial region
avg_enso = sst_enso.sst.groupby('time').mean(dim=['lat','lon'])
avg_enso.plot()
```

[image: average temperature for enso3.4 region]

This figure matches that shown at the bottom of the tutorial. so far so good, but i'd like to compute and plot ONI as well.   Warm or cold phases of the Oceanic Nino Index are defined by a five consecutive 3-month running mean of sea surface temperature (SST) anomalies in the Niño 3.4 region that is above (below) the threshold of +0.5°C (-0.5°C). This is known as the Oceanic Niño Index (ONI).

I run into trouble because the `month` becomes an index.
**Q1. I'm not sure how to make sure that subtracting `sst_enso` - `enso_clim` results in the correct math.**
Assuming that is correct, I can compute the regional mean anomaly again and then use a rolling window mean.

```
enso_clim = sst_enso.sst.groupby('time.month').mean('time')
sst_anom = sst_enso - enso_clim
enso_anom = sst_anom.groupby('time').mean(dim=['lat','lon'])
oni = enso_anom.rolling(time = 3).mean()
```

Now I'd like to plot a bar chart of oni with positive red, negative blue. Something like this:
[image: example red/blue bar graph]

for exaample with:

```
oni.sst.plot.bar(color=(oni.sst < 0).map({True: 'b', False: 'r'}))
```

Instead `oni.sst.plot()` gives me:

[image: month x year oni]

Resetting the index `enso_anom.reset_index('month', drop=True).sst` still keeps `month` as a dimension and gives the same plot. If you `drop_dims('month')` then the sst data goes away.

I also tried converting to a pd with `oni.to_dataframe()` but you end up with 5040 rows which is 12 months x 420 month-years I subsetted for.  According to the [docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_dataframe.html?highlight=to_dataframe) "The DataFrame is indexed by the Cartesian product of index coordinates (in the form of a pandas.MultiIndex)." so I guess that makes sense, but not useful. Even if you reset_index of oni before converting to a dataframe you get the same 5040 rows.  **Q2. Since the dataframe must be repeating itself I can probably figure out where, but is there a way to do this "cleaner" with each date not repeated for all 12 months?**

Answer (score 1):

Your code results into an DataArray with the dimensions time and month due to the
re-chunking. This is the reason why you end up with such a plot.

There is a trick (found [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#Calculate-monthly-anomalies)) to calculate anomalies. Besides this I would select as a reference period 1986-2015 ( see [NOAA definition for ONI-index](https://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_change.shtml)).

Combining both I ended up in this short code (without the bar plots):

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# load all files
ds_all = xr.open_mfdataset('./tutorial-data/sst/*nc', combine='by_coords')
# slice for enso3.4 region
sst_enso = ds_all.sel(lat=slice(-5,5), lon=slice(-170+360,-120+360))
avg_enso = sst_enso.sst.groupby('time').mean(dim=['lat','lon'])
avg_enso.plot()

ds = sst_enso.sst.mean(dim=['lat','lon'])
enso_clim = ds.sel(time=slice('1986-01-01', '2016-01-01')).groupby("time.month").mean("time")
# ref: https://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_change.shtml
enso_anom = ds.groupby("time.month") - enso_clim
# ref: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#Calculate-monthly-anomalies

enso_anom.plot()

oni = enso_anom.rolling(time = 3).mean()
oni.plot()
```

Comment: I removed the ending part because everyone who answers will hope that their answer will help and you can be recognized by your profile card under your answer.  Just remember that for future posts :)